# How to load ropevim only when editing Python files

Tags: vim, clojure, rope

I'm using ropevim for some operations on Python files, and vimclojure for Clojure files and REPL.

VimClojure only loaded when editing Clojure files, but ropevim loaded for every file, and this addons have some same keybindigs, so for example, when editing Clojure files, `<leader>rf` calls ropevim's RopeRename command, but it should call vimclojure's RequireFile command.

How can I make ropevim load only when editing Python files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.vimrc`:

`au FileType python source <plugin name>`, and a similar one for clojure.

Comment: Anyone who wants to go into more detail, feel free to edit this answer.